# Compare rows from two join tables and gives result from two tables in alternate fashion

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

```
Table X

First Name    Last Name    Job
----------    ---------    ---
CHIN          JACK         A
GREEN         JAMES        B

Table Y

First Name    Last Name    Job
----------    ---------    ---
CHIN          JACK         D
GREEN         JAMES        B


  RESULT
------
First Name          Last Name           Job
----------          ---------           ---
CHIN                JACK                >> A <<   --(first row from Table X)
CHIN                JACK                >> D <<   --(first row from Table Y)
>> CHIN <<          >> JACK <<          >> A <<   --(first row from Table X)
>> GREEN <<         >> JAMES <<         >> B <<   --(second row from Table Y)
>> GREEN <<         >> JAMES <<         >> B <<   --(second row from Table X)
>> CHIN <<          >> JACK <<          >> D <<   --(first row from Table Y)
GREEN               JAMES               B         --(second row from Table X) 
GREEN               JAMES               B         --(second row from Table Y)
```

I am trying to compare rows from two tables on a column by column basis. If there is a mismatch in column values between two tables I highlight it by appending '>> <<' for the mismatch field in both tables TableX and TableY in the result table. Result table has row from TableX and TableY alternately. Please see the result table to get a better idea on my expected result.

Last two tables of the result set is optional. I am okay with having it or not having it.

This query is what I initially thought of but it doesn't give rows from two tables alternately and it takes into account only column values in TableX
Is there a possible way to write a query to achieve the result table. Please advise.

```
SELECT
CASE
  WHEN x.firstname = y.firstname THEN x.firstname
  ELSE '>> '+x.firstname+' <<'
END FirstName,
CASE 
  WHEN x.lastname = y.lastname THEN x.lastname
  ELSE '>> '+x.lastname+' <<'
END LastName,
CASE 
  WHEN x.job = y.job THEN x.job
  ELSE '>> '+x.job+' <<'
END Job
FROM
TableX x
JOIN
TableY y
ON x.firstname <> y.firstname
OR x.lastname <> y.lastname
OR x.job <> y.job
```

Improvement
I figured out a query that very much resembles my expected result. I achieved it by adding a new column 'Company' who values is always the same in TableX and TableY. So now the table looks like

Table X

```
Company    First Name    Last Name    Job
-------    ----------    ---------    ---
C          CHIN          JACK         A
C          GREEN         JAMES        B
```

Table Y

```
Company    First Name    Last Name    Job
-------    ----------    ---------    ---
T          CHIN          JACK         D
T          GREEN         JAMES        B
```

And this is my new query

```
    SELECT
    *
FROM 
(
SELECT      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY x.Company) as RowNumber,
            1 AS 'RowOrder',
            x.TableName,
            CASE
                WHEN x.firstname = y.firstname THEN x.firstname
                ELSE '>> '+x.firstname+' <<'
            END FirstName,
            CASE
                WHEN x.LastName = y.LastName THEN x.LastName
                ELSE '>> '+x.LastName+' <<'
            END LastName,
            CASE
                WHEN x.Job = y.Job THEN x.Job
                ELSE '>> '+x.Job+' <<'
            END Job
    FROM
            #tableX x
        JOIN #tableY y
        ON x.FirstName <> y.FirstName
        OR x.LastName <> y.LastName
        OR x.Job <> y.Job

UNION ALL

SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY y.Company) as RowNumber,
            2 AS 'RowOrder',
            y.TableName,
            CASE
                WHEN x.firstname = y.firstname THEN y.firstname
                ELSE '>> '+y.firstname+' <<'
            END FirstName,
            CASE
                WHEN x.LastName = y.LastName THEN y.LastName
                ELSE '>> '+y.LastName+' <<'
            END LastName,
            CASE
                WHEN x.Job = y.Job THEN y.Job
                ELSE '>> '+y.Job+' <<'
            END Job
    FROM
            #tableX x
        JOIN #tableY y
        ON x.FirstName <> y.FirstName
        OR x.LastName <> y.LastName
        OR x.Job <> y.Job

) rt
ORDER BY rt.RowNumber, rt.RowOrder
```

Now the problem is that the join in the second select statement inside braces scrambles the order in which the rows are displayed. This results in wrong ordering of rows in the final result. Please find the final result below. You can also find the individual select statements inside the braces. The last table in the picture gives the rows in scrambled order which messes up the final result.

[Final result, result from first select statement, result from second select statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8jIM.png)

Comment: Why don't you display differences horizontally instead of vertically? That seems like a much easier way to do the query that lets you study the data perfectly well. And why do you want to display `GREEN JAMES B` when comparing to `CHIN JACK A`? That row seems to have no correspondence to it, if you're matching on name. If you're not matching on name, what is the rule for matching and what rows you want to display next to the comparison or anchor one?

Comment: What is the order that you want them to appear in?  Keep in mind that despite how it may appear, SQL tables *have no inherent order of their own*, so saying "the first/second/third/etc row" from a table has no meaning unless you define an order based on key values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it you want to compare all pairs of rows between two tables. Just realize this is going to get big and slow very quickly.

```
with X as (
    select *, row_number() over (order by "First Name", "Last Name", "Job") as rnX
    from TableX
), Y as (
    select *, row_number() over (order by "First Name", "Last Name", "Job") as rnY
    from TableY
), horizontal as (
    select
        rnX, rnY,
        case when x."First Name" = y."First Name" then x."First Name"
            else '>> ' + x."First Name" + ' <<' end as FirstNameX,
        case when x."First Name" = y."First Name" then y."First Name"
            else '>> ' + y."First Name" + ' <<' end as FirstNameY,
        case when x."Last Name" = y."Last Name" then x."Last Name"
            else '>> ' + x."Last Name" + ' <<' end as LastNameX,
        case when x."Last Name" = y."Last Name" then y."Last Name"
            else '>> ' + y."Last Name" + ' <<' end as LastNameY,
        case when x."Job" = y."Job" then x."Job"
            else '>> ' + x."Job" + ' <<' end as JobX,
        case when x."Job" = y."Job" then y."Job"
            else '>> ' + y."Job" + ' <<' end as JobY
    from X as x cross join Y as y
), interleave as (
    select
        rnX, rnY, n,
        case when n = 1 then 'X' else 'Y' end as src,
        case when n = 1 then rnX else rnY end as rn,
        case when n = 1 then FirstNameX else FirstNameY end as "First Name",
        case when n = 1 then LastNameX else LastNameY end as "Last Name",
        case when n = 1 then JobX else JobY end as "Job"
    from horizontal cross apply (select n from (values (1), (2)) d(n)) c
)
select src, rn, "First Name", "Last Name", "Job" from interleave
order by rnX, rnY, n;
```

http://rextester.com/JRQ91122